# Cant see another view type in recycler view

Tags: java, android, layout, view, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in that I want to show two layouts. For that I am using view type and different view holders. And loaded accordingly, but I can only see the list of items and not the header layout.

Not  getting any error to recognize any issue. As I did debug found that its not going inside another view type, the layout is not getting shown.

Adapter :

```
public class TransportListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Transport> list;
        private TransportListFragment transportListFragment;
        static final int TYPE_LOAD_TRANSPORT = 0, TYPE_LOAD_PROGRESS = 2, LOAD_TRANSPORT_ITEMS_HEADER = 1;


        public TransportListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Transport> list,TransportListFragment transportListFragment) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
            this.transportListFragment = transportListFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            switch (viewType) {

                case LOAD_TRANSPORT_ITEMS_HEADER:
                    View v_order_header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transport_rout, parent, false);
                    viewHolder = new LoadTransportHeader(v_order_header);
                    break;

                case TYPE_LOAD_TRANSPORT:
                    View v_order_items = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transport_item, parent, false);
                    viewHolder = new TransportListHolder(v_order_items);
                    break;

            }

            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LOAD_TRANSPORT) {
                TransportListHolder transportListHolder = (TransportListHolder) holder;
                retriveAllTransports(transportListHolder, position);
            }
            else if (getItemViewType(position) == LOAD_TRANSPORT_ITEMS_HEADER ) {
                LoadTransportHeader loadTransportHeader = (LoadTransportHeader) holder;
                retriveTransportHeader(loadTransportHeader, position);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            Object obj = list.get(position);

            if (obj instanceof Transport) {
                return TYPE_LOAD_TRANSPORT;
            }
            else if (obj instanceof LoadTransportHeader) return LOAD_TRANSPORT_ITEMS_HEADER;

            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

    public void retriveTransportHeader(final LoadTransportHeader holder, int position) {

    }
        public void retriveAllTransports(final TransportListHolder holder, int position) {

            final Transport data = (Transport) list.get(position);

            holder.tv_product.setText(data.getmProductName());
            holder.tv_dateTime.setText(data.getmDateTime());
            holder.tv_username.setText(String.valueOf(data.getmUserName()));

            String url = "http://104.131.162.126/testslim/v1/src/images/" + data.getmProductImg();

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .resize(400, 400)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.product)
                    .error(R.drawable.product)
                    .into(holder.img_product);
        }

}
```

Please help. Thank you..

Comment: remove return super.getItemViewType(position); from getItemViewType

Comment: then what should I return? its asking for a return statement. @DivyeshPatel

Comment: then return any except view holder type

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList list;

You are just passing one type of array which is Transport

```
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Object obj = list.get(position); // list is of only type Transport

        if (obj instanceof Transport) {
            return TYPE_LOAD_TRANSPORT;  // it will always return this
        }
        else if (obj instanceof LoadTransportHeader) return LOAD_TRANSPORT_ITEMS_HEADER;

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change `private ArrayList<Transport>` list into `private ArrayList<Object> list;`

it show one type because of your List only for Transport object.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Object obj = list.get(position);

        if (obj instanceof Transport) {
            return TYPE_LOAD_TRANSPORT;
        }
        else if (obj instanceof LoadTransportHeader) 
            return LOAD_TRANSPORT_ITEMS_HEADER;

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
```

in Activty/Fragment..

```
List<Object> objects = new Arraylist();
objects.add(new Transport("","",""));
objects.add(new LoadTransportHeader("","",""));
objects.add(new Transport("","",""));
objects.add(new LoadTransportHeader("","",""));
```